# Accessing the App (client) ID from an Azure App Service in bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-bicep, azure-appservice

In bicep, I am configuring an Azure API Management policy that enables the managed service identity for a specific backend App Service.

This is typically done by setting an XML fragment like this:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="4d192d04-XXXX-461f-a6ab-XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
        <base />
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

What I am now looking for, is how to retrieve that specific `resource` id from the existing App Service, in my bicep template.

Some fragments from my existing bicep template below:

```yaml
// The App Service declaration
@description('API Website')
resource backendapi 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' = {
  name: 'backend-${environment}'
  kind: 'app,linux,container'
  location: location
  // left out properties, etc for brevity

// This is where I want to retrieve the client ID from that web app, but this fails:
var managed_identity_id = backendapi.identity.principalId
```

When deploying the above template, I get the following exception (although the `identity.principalId` was indicated to be valid by the Visual Studio Code intellisense.

> The language expression property 'identity' doesn't exist, available properties are 'apiVersion, location, tags, kind, properties, condition, deploymentResourceLineInfo, existing, isConditionTrue, subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, scope, resourceId, referenceApiVersion, isTemplateResource, isAction, provisioningOperation'

So my question is, how can I access the property from an App Service, in a bicep file.  The property of which the value is shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you specify an identity?   identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }

Comment: I guess you are looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2020-12-01/sites/config-authsettingsv2?tabs=bicep

Comment: yep here you're trying to get the client id of the app registration to authenticate to your app not the managed identity of your app. the auth settings should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comment section, you are looking for the web app auth settings: [Microsoft.Web sites/config 'authsettingsV2' 2020-12-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2020-12-01/sites/config-authsettingsv2?tabs=bicep)

You could retrieve the clientId for AzureAD Auth Like that:

```bicep
param webAppName string

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: webAppName
}

resource authsettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-09-01' existing = {
  name: 'authsettingsV2'
  parent: webApp
}

var clientId = authsettings.properties.identityProviders.azureActiveDirectory.registration.clientId
```

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed what I was looking for.  Appreciated!  Also props to Markus for helping out